# Retrieving names of people who performed a specific action and personalising the message

Tags: sql

I have an Actions table that records the actions taken by the users:

```
ActionId, UserId
```

The **Actions** table holds the name and other details about the action, and **Users** table similarly holds the name and details about the users.

Now, in my application, I want to inform a user about the actions his friends have taken, something like:

> "Person A, Person B, Person C have
>   taken this action."

To do that, I am currently using GROUP_CONCAT() to concat the names of the people like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Actions ON Users.UserId = Actions.UserId
WHERE ActionId = '123'
```

**However**, I want to personalise this message in two ways.

1. I want a "..., and " before the last user, so it sounds more natural than a machine generated list.
2. In cases where the user is also one of the people who have taken this action, I want to display a message like:

> "Person A, Person B, Person C and **you**
>   have taken this action."

What's the most elegant way to achieve this? I am looking for a solution which is efficient enough for a large scale system.

Comment: Assuming that you're pulling this data out into a web application, then do the data mangling there, SQL will never be elegant for that, that's not its forte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really there's no elegant way to do this sort of thing in SQL. You could of course write a cursor that's checking for various conditions and building the string as you go along.